# How to pass the value to javascript in html.erb rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to pass the value `user.skypeid` to a javascript code `participants` in html.erb. What is the right way to do it? The below approach doesn't work for me.

```
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= user.name %></td>
  <td><%= user.skypeid %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Show', user_path(user) %></td>
  <td>
    <div id="SkypeButton_Call_aaa_1">
     <script type="text/javascript">
     Skype.ui({
     "name": "call",
     "element": "SkypeButton_Call_aaa_1",
     "participants": [user.skypeid]
     });
     </script>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must print it as embedded ruby, and wrap it within quotes:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.name %></td>
    <td><%= user.skypeid %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', user_path(user) %></td>
    <td>
      <div id="SkypeButton_Call_aaa_1">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        Skype.ui({
          "name": "call",
          "element": "SkypeButton_Call_aaa_1",
          "participants": ['<%= user.skypeid %>']
        });
       </script>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Although you could move the script it outside or to another file:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr class="">
    <td><%= user.name %></td>
    <td><%= user.skypeid %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', user_path(user) %></td>
    <td>
      <div id="SkypeButton_Call_aaa_1" data-skype="<%= user.skypeid %>"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  let id = 'SkypeButton_Call_aaa_1'
  let user = document.getElementById(id).dataset
  Skype.ui({
    'name': 'call', 'element': id, 'participants': [user.skype]
  })
</script>
```

Comment: I am pretty new to rails. That's what I was planning to do next once I get a working version. It nice of you add that information. Thanks again! Will definitely accept this answer.

Comment: The only problem I have is that, the skype buttons are not appearing in the same row. Instead, the buttons appears all in the beginning of the page one after the other. How can I get them in the same row? Thanks

Comment: That's great, I've never used that Skype.ui, but I assume there must be an identifier to where put them, are you dealing fine with that?, maybe you're using in all cases the same, that's way they appear in the same place.

Comment: In the second method you have mentioned, don't you have to enclose the javascript code inside a function and call that function from the <div id="skypeid"..> </div>? Thanks